# Cloudfoundry Multi VM

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am pretty new to cloudfoundry. I am still trying to understand how exactly it works.

Say if I have three VMs. VM *1* is running on server *A*. 
VM *2* and *3* are running on server *B*.
If I wanted to use a single CloudFoundry Instance on those three, would it work?

And if not, how could I use Cloudfoundry on multiple servers or at least multiple VMs? I know I can use BOSH to set them up, but do I still have to manage each instance seperately?

Thank you:
Jannis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOSH will deploy VMs for you, you typically don't deploy Cloud Foundry onto existing VMs.  BOSH supports deploying to several infrastructures.  The core supported infrastructures include AWS, vSphere, OpenStack, and vCloud Air/vCloud Director.  There are also community-provided "Cloud Provider Interfaces" for IBM SoftLayer, Azure, Google Compute Engine, and more.

Cloud Foundry is meant to be run as a distributed service, i.e. on multiple VMs.  Typically those VMs will be on multiple different hosts, hardware racks, servers, datacenters, what have you.  And BOSH is designed to facilitate deploying and managing distributed services like Cloud Foundry.  So no, you do not need to manage individual VMs separately.

You can read more about [BOSH](https://bosh.io) and [Deploying Cloud Foundry](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying).

Comment: thank you. As I understand it this would mean, that if I just have two servers and nothing else, I would (more or less) simply install an OpenStack Infratructure on those and then tell BOSH to install CloudFoundry. Thereafter the infratructure is no different from what I would have if I set this up on a single server.
Is this correct?